# OneDrive API 2.0 for buisness returns http status code 200 instead of 302 for download API

Tags: onedrive

Download API for OneDrive for business 'GET /drive/items/{item-id}/content' returns file content with 200 HTTP status. Document 'https://dev.onedrive.com/items/download.htm'  says, It will return 302 Found response with Location.

I am trying to hit the request using rest client.

even i tried providing if-none-match header with etag value, where in i was expecting an HTTP 304 Not Modified. in turn it returned 200 OK response.

Is it a known issue?

Thanks
Sonia

Comment: Are you actually getting back the content of the file, or something altogether different? Also, is that the actual URL you're using or just a shorthand?

Comment: Yes. I actually get the content of the file.

Comment: URL is just a shorthand. actual URL is  https://persistentsystemsltd294-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me/drive//items/01XIKRU6NUPWDTLHX3FFAYFEWF6T2K6NRL/content

Comment: Can you tell us how you're making the request that's getting a 200, specifically, is it possible whatever you're doing is automatically following the redirect? As for the lack of 304, are you including the quotes around the `If-None-Match` header or are they being stripped (they should be there)?